# Select2 autocomplete not working when bind element names are different

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 3.5.2. When trying to bind to an array of `label` and `value` instead of `id` and `text`, Select2 autocomplete is not working. Can you let me know if there are any options that I am missing?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var optionsList = [{value: 1, label: 'first'}, {value: 2, label: 'second'}, {value: 3, label: 'third'}, {value: 4, label: 'fourth'}];

  $("#example_select2").select2({ 
    data: optionsList,
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    id: 'value',
    formatResult : function(item) { return item.label; },
    formatSelection: function(item) { return item.label; }                        
  });
});
```

```css
</style><!-- Ugly Hack -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```html
<div id="example_select2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are seeing is not because of the `id` being changed, but it is because you are using `label` instead of `text` in your data objects. Select2 will do matching by default on the `text` key of the object, so it makes sense that it can't find anything if you aren't setting it.

You can fix this by either changing your array data to use `text`, or re-mapping the `value` key to the `text` key. I would also recommend doing this for your `value` key (making it be `id`), but that's not required because Select2 3.5.2 supports the `id` option. [Select2 4.0.0 does not.](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#changed-id)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var optionsList = $.map(
    [{value: 1, label: 'first'}, {value: 2, label: 'second'}, {value: 3, label: 'third'}, {value: 4, label: 'fourth'}],
    function (obj) {
  obj.id = obj.id || obj.value;
  obj.text = obj.text || obj.label;
 
  return obj;
});

  $("#example_select2").select2({ 
    data: optionsList,
    dropdownAutoWidth: true                       
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input id="example_select2" type="text">
```

Select2 also does not support being attached to a `<div>` element, so I have swapped it out with the more JavaScript-disabled-friendly `<input type="text" />` element.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to translate the label/value to text/id. Was just trying to avoid doing the translation but looks like that is the only option.